# Non-rectangular fragments / intertwined layouts

Tags: android, android-fragments

I guess the pic pretty much explains it: is something like this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Not really, as you can't have any type of `Layout` with this shape. But you can cheat a bit and make user to think it is like this. Just set content in layout B in the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `RelativeLayout` to achieve this type of layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FFFF"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing stops you from having overlapping layouts like in Krrishnaaaa's answer.

Depending on what `Views` you want to keep there you may try things similar to these, where you split fragment B into two separate:

[image: small fragment]

[image: horizontal full width fragment]